# Best practice to create xml messages with DOMDocument class

Tags: php, xml, class, dom

I want to create xml messages for webservice communication.
These messages should be created from a pool of reusable elements.
Therefore I have created different classes. 
A "factory" class, that only returns a message class.
An element class, that consists of the reusable parts and the message classes that are the blueprints for the desired xml messages.

My code delivers the expected result, but I`m looking for a best practice.
Especially a way to get rid of rewriting the same *save()* and *__construct* method in every of the message classes.

Thanks in advance

```
    // class to create webservice messages
class Messages{

    private function __construct(){}

    public static function get($type) {
        //some error handling if class not exists
        return new $type;
    }
}

// message no.1
class Message_1 extends Elements{

    protected $root;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->root = $this->createElement("message1");
    }

    public function add_anotherElement(){
        $this->root->appendChild($this->add_anotherElementBlock("foo", "bar"));
    }

    public function add_element(){
        $this->root->appendChild($this->add_someElementBlock("foo", "bar"));
    }

    public function save(){
        return $this->saveXML($this->root);
    }
}

// message no.2
class Message_2 extends Elements {

    protected $root;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->root = $this->createElement("message2");
    }

    public function add_elements(){
        $this->root->appendChild($this->add_anotherElementBlock("foo", "bar"));
        $this->root->appendChild($this->add_someElementBlock("foo", "bar"));
    }

    public function save(){
        return $this->saveXML($this->root);
    }
}

// reusable elements
class Elements extends DOMDocument{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function add_someElementBlock($foo, $bar) {
        $node = $this->createElement("root");

        $attr = $this->createAttribute("id");
        $attr->value = $foo;
        $node->appendChild($attr);

        $subnode = $this->createElement("sub",$bar);

        $node->appendChild($subnode);

        return $node;
    }

    public function add_anotherElementBlock($foo, $bar) {
        $node = $this->createElement("anotherRoot");

        $subnode = $this->createElement("anotherSubNode",$bar);
        $attr = $this->createAttribute("anotherAttribute");
        $attr->value = $foo;
        $subnode->appendChild($attr);

        $node->appendChild($subnode);

        return $node;
    }
}

$message1 = Messages::get('Message_1');
$message1->add_element();
$message1->add_anotherElement();


$message2 = Messages::get('Message_2');
$message2->add_elements();

//********************************************
echo "<pre>";
print_r(htmlentities($message1->save()));
echo "</pre>";
echo "<hr />";
echo "<pre>";
print_r(htmlentities($message2->save()));
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: The code looks not that bad. Just a hint: While static factory methods are widely deployed they don't have to be. Creating (and customizing) a factory as an object can have advantages...

Comment: I see no reason why `root` is `private`. Make it `protected`. This applies to every element unless you can say surely "I want that it is private, because ... " Mostly you won't find a reason. It has to be said that too much books are wrong with `private` usage

Comment: Also I would generalize the factory method, like this: `public function factory($messageType)` .. This would allow you to add messages classes without extending the factory...

Comment: I guess there are more issues, but I was too lazy to get more into the details of XML creation... Code review end.. :) (note that code reviews are better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ )

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Especially to design the "factory" a little more flexible. I edited my example, except that I kept it static. Maybe I change it later, but this isn't the straw that broke the camel's back ;-)

Comment: Yes, a static factory is ok so far. Also the whole code looks basically good. I just say *basically* because I've never used it, never played around with it. You'll likely find more issues after some time of usage. Normally I don't upvote review questions here, because they are normally off topic here... but however, why not upvoting someone who really likes code? :) +1

Comment: Declare `root` once, in `Elements`.. Also drop the `__construct()` from `Elements` it is not required as it just calls the parent constructor, what is the default action

Comment: Put `save()` to `Elements`. (Note that code duplication shows that something is wrong)

Comment: Thank you very much. Had the same idea 2 minutes ago. Sometimes I dont see the obvious.

Comment: Your mentioning that I should use protected instead of private was the decisive factor

Comment: Questions like this should really be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  Here it is off-topic as primaarily opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Have openend a question at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42327/best-practice-to-create-xml-messages-with-domdocument-class-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to hek2mgl advices I changed my classes. Seems good to me, hope anyone found it helpful too.

```
// class to create webservice messages
class Messages{

    private function __construct(){}

    public static function get($type) {
        //some error handling if class not exists
        return new $type;
    }
}

// message no.1
class Message_1 extends Elements{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->root = $this->createElement("message1");
    }

    public function add_anotherElement(){
        $this->root->appendChild($this->add_anotherElementBlock("foo", "bar"));
    }

    public function add_element(){
        $this->root->appendChild($this->add_someElementBlock("foo", "bar"));
    }
}

// message no.2
class Message_2 extends Elements {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->root = $this->createElement("message2");
    }

    public function add_elements(){
        $this->root->appendChild($this->add_anotherElementBlock("foo", "bar"));
        $this->root->appendChild($this->add_someElementBlock("foo", "bar"));
    }

}

// message no.3
class Message_3 extends Elements {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->root = $this->createElement("message3");
    }

    public function add_element(){
        // unique Element
        $this->root->appendChild($this->createElement("foo", "bar"));
    }

}

// reusable elements
class Elements extends DOMDocument{

    protected $root;

    public function __construct() {
    }

    protected function add_someElementBlock($foo, $bar) {
        $node = $this->createElement("root");

        $attr = $this->createAttribute("id");
        $attr->value = $foo;
        $node->appendChild($attr);

        $subnode = $this->createElement("sub",$bar);

        $node->appendChild($subnode);

        return $node;
    }

    protected function add_anotherElementBlock($foo, $bar) {
        $node = $this->createElement("anotherRoot");

        $subnode = $this->createElement("anotherSubNode",$bar);
        $attr = $this->createAttribute("anotherAttribute");
        $attr->value = $foo;
        $subnode->appendChild($attr);

        $node->appendChild($subnode);

        return $node;
    }

    public function getMessage(){
        return $this->saveXML($this->root);
    }
}

$message1 = Messages::get('Message_1');
$message1->add_element();
$message1->add_anotherElement();

$message2 = Messages::get('Message_2');
$message2->add_elements();

$message3 = Messages::get('Message_3');
$message3->add_element();

//********************************************
echo "<pre>";
print_r(htmlentities($message1->getMessage()));
echo "</pre>";
echo "<hr />";
echo "<pre>";
print_r(htmlentities($message2->getMessage()));
echo "</pre>";
echo "<hr />";
echo "<pre>";
print_r(htmlentities($message3->getMessage()));
echo "</pre>";
```